# SQL Deriving Financial year (20XX/YY) from dd/mm/yyyy SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, financial

My financial year is 01/04/20X0 to 31/03/20X1. So current financial year runs from 01/04/2018 to 31/03/2019. This is abbreviated to "20X0/X1"  or "2018/19".

My output date is 01/08/2021 and is always of the format dd/mm/yyyy. This corresponds to Financial Year "2021/22"

I need help deriving a formula that is foolproof to return the financial year from my date or any given date of the format dd/mm/yyyy.

I do not want to use a Case statement as there will be several bands and does not seem efficient.

This is currently what I am using but is faulty

```
CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, 9, ISNULL(msdate5.[Completion - Revised], msdate5.[Completion - Original])))-1 as nvarchar) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, 9, ISNULL( msdate5.[Completion - Revised],  msdate5.[Completion - Original]))) as nvarchar)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When declaring a `(n)varchar`, `(n)char`, etc, always make sure you declare the length. I.e. `nvarchar(10)`. You can have some "nasty" surprises if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
select (datename(year, dateadd(month, -3, @mydate)) + '/' +
        datename(year, dateadd(month, -3 + 12, @mydate))
       )
```

This offsets the date by three months and extracts the year.  Note the use of `datename()` so you don't have to bother with converting anything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

For today, this returns `'2018/19'`. For things like this, one of the easiest methods is to align to fiscal year with the calendar year, and then work from there:

```
DECLARE @Date date = GETDATE();

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(4),DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @Date))) + '/' + RIGHT(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @Date)) +1,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Larnu. Though I won't be using this solution, I have learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mydate VARCHAR(20) = '01/08/2021'

SELECT cast(datepart(year, @mydate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + cast((datepart(year, @mydate) + 1) AS VARCHAR(4))

SELECT cast(cast(datepart(year, @mydate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + '04' + '/' + '01' AS DATETIME)
    ,cast(cast((datepart(year, @mydate) + 1) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + '03' + '/' + '31' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response KumarHarsh. I am going to use the above solution as it is not so hefty. Kind regards, Dasal